# How to add multiple content control on same window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have window where I have load 4 views. 2 each on a content control.

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10"/>
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DeviceListView" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:DeviceViewModel}">
            <views:DeviceList DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="TestCaseListView" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:TestCaseViewModel}">
            <views:TestCaseView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

By this I am using content control.

Please suggest how to use multiple content control on same window.

Comment: Right now using only one content control on window. I have to use 2 content control area where I can toggle between multiple views.

Comment: ItemsControl uses multiple ContentPresenters to visualize multiple items from its ItemsSource collection.